# MongoDB schema design for unbounded growing table

Tags: mongodb, schema

I'm practicing on MongoDB through a small personal project,
in which, may encounter a need to store some intermediate data abstracted as a **unbounded growing table**. Both rows and columns would grow boundlessly.

The usage of this abstract table is that I want to be able to

- know the corresponding column for each entry in a row
- know the corresponding row for each entry in a column

Or, in other word, *know the index of each table entry*

Hence there comes up two choices to model the table:

1. Make two collections:

   - one holds each row as a document which embeds a growing structure as row entries to have reference to the corresponding columns;
   - and similarly, another collection holds each column as a document embedding a growing structure to reference to the corresponding rows.
2. Make a <strike>single</strike> separate collection that holds each table entry as a document. Hence each document size is fixed.

The first model has problem with [document growth](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-model-operations/#data-model-document-growth) (In fact, in my application, the table grows a bit askew, and only one collection would encounter document growth issue). The second model seems fine to me. Is there some pitfall or some other issue that should be aware of? And what is the common practice to deal with such problem?

---

### UPDATE: explain things in more detail

I am trying to do [automatic summarization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_summarization) of an ongoing conversation. The input is a corpus of sentences, and terms are extracted from each sentences. For example, English terms are [stemmed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming), and sentences in [CJK languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_characters) are [segmented](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_segmentation). Hence obtained a term-sentence matrix. Then one of the method needs to compute [(sparse) SVD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) of such term-sentence matrix.

The sentences and extracted terms would be stored into the database. But the term-sentence matrix would grow unbounded.

(Or one can think of the problem of storing a mapping between *tweets* and *hashtags*)

There were two choices of draft schema that comes up to my mind:

#### choice one (hold two-way linkages between sentences and terms)

```
{  // sentence collection doc
    "_id" : // generated by timestamp
    , "text" : //
    , "contained_terms" : [
        // an array of "_id"s in term collection
    ]
}

{   // term collection doc
    "_id" : // use term name
    , "in_sentences" : [
        // an array of "_id"s in sentence collection
    ]
}
```

#### choice two (make linkages into a separate collection)

```
{   // linkage collection doc (as matrix entries)
    "_id" : // generated by timestamp
    , "term" : // an "_id" in term collection
    , "in_sentence" : // an "_id" in sentence collection
}

{   // sentence collection doc
    "_id" : // generated by time stamp
    , "text" : //
}

{   // term collection doc
    "_id" : // use term name
}
```

The *choice one* encounters [document growth](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-model-operations/#data-model-document-growth) problem because *"in sentences"* array of a *term collection doc* is very likely to grow beyond limit when sentences come in nonstop.

The *choice two* extract the linkage between terms and sentences into a separate collection, hence avoids the document growth. Although querying "which sentences contain the term" costs more, but in the end, it seems I don't actually need such operation much.

Currently, I'm thinking that the *choice two* better suit my needs. The linkage collection seems conform to the input of sparse SVD. To speed up computation, very high frequency terms can be filtered out if the term frequency field is added to each term collection docs (or in a separate collection when there are more than one conversations). This filtering seems fine in the case of automatic summarization.

But still wonder

- Is there some issues or pitfalls that should be aware of?
- What is the common practice for similar situation?

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to achieve in terms of real world problem, and we may be able to suggest schema implementations that help. The problem explained doesn't make much sense (to me).

Comment: I just update with more concrete explanation. But I would more like to know the common practice of similar situation than just this specific application of my current project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding of mongodb is that you need to design your schema around your queries. So how you save your data is highly dependent on what data will you be querying. So even for the same set of data, your schema can vary depending on the actual use case. Additionally, data redundancy is quite common in NoSql database design. In case you are going to need some data again and again, there is no point in saving it in a separate collection. You can duplicate it in 2 collections, and that's a fair enough cost for faster querying. Memory is cheap, processing isn't! Additionally, pre-aggregation helps in case of mongo for huge data sets. Your queries will work fine for decent number of documents, but once you go into the realm of millions of records, you may face problems with a certain class of queries like counts, aggregation, etc. Pre-aggregation helps in keeping things real time, though it may have a higher write/insertion overhead. Always avoid a full table scan, whenever you can.

Above are some broad level concepts that I find relevant to your question. I'll try and explain it in your context with some examples (as I am not sure what data you are eventually going to need, or the queries you will do).

Let's say you are going to need `terms` per `sentence` frequently, to highlight them. In that case the recommended schema will be:

```
{   "_id" : // sentence id - you will query on this
    , "text" : // sentence text
    , "terms" : ["term1", "term2", "term3"]
}
```

So for each new sentence, you extract all the terms and save it (not the id) along with the sentence. The advantage here being that you will not need to query for the term separately. You can get all the terms for a given sentence in a single query. Additionally, the document size doesn't grow, and hence no document relocation.

Let's say you also want to have a unique list of terms and some per term meta data. You can have a separate terms collection which has a list of all the unique terms:

```
{ "_id": ,
  , "term": //term
  , "meaning":
  , "metadata""
  , "count": 1 
}
```

You can have a unique index on term. Each time you extract terms from a sentence, you look up for it in this collection, and in case you don't find it, you insert it. Now let's say you also want to maintain a count of term appearance. So each time you find a term in a sentence and do a lookup in terms collection, you can increment (atomic) the count as well - pre-aggregation. If you add an index on count, you can get the top 100 terms, etc. easily on the fly.

Now let's say you want to query/count all the sentences with a given term. You can add an index on terms array and directly look up for all the sentences with a given term:

`Sentence.where(:term => "term1").count  //mongoid query`

Again, you are achieving this with a single query, as opposed to getting a term id first in your case, and then the sentences.

Other than this it's always advisable to ensure that your working set and indexes fit into RAM for best performance.

So again, there are no right and wrong answers for schema design and it definitely depends on the queries you will be doing. I would also advise you to unlearn some of your relational DB concepts when trying to design for NoSQL databases. I learned it the hard way =) Hope some of this helps you in coming up with an efficient schema for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to model a matrix with the whole collection representing the matrix, I think the go-to model should be to have each entry (row i, column j) as a document. If you put in a field like `"index" : { "row" : i, "column" : j}` and appropriate indices then it's easy and fast to do fun things like

- get the entry at (i, j)
- get row i
- get column j

The matrix is represented sparsely so if row i only has 10 columns with values, row i is just 10 documents. If the rows/columns really do grow unboundedly to very large sizes then modeling a document as a row or column or something of "1 dimension" could hit the hard 16MB BSON document size limit.

I'm thinking the biggest drawback could be large index sizes given that every entry is its own document.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and when I rethink my need, it seems the emphasis I was put on is not so important to my application. But still, the separation of the "entry" seems a better model to avoid document growth problem.